# How can I use Wireshark on a MacBook Air?

Tags: wifi, network, macbook-pro, wireshark

I have a new MacBook Air. I would like to run Wireshark on it. But when I choose capture in Wireshark there is no interfaces to capture from. Doesn't Wireshark have support for the MacBook Air WiFi nic?

How can I use Wireshark on a MacBook Air?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the right permissions.

Go into Terminal and enter the following commands:

```
cd /Library/StartupItems  
sudo chown -R root:wheel ChmodBPF
```

You might need to restart the computer to take effect.  You also need to be admin (a sudoer) to perform these commands

I should mention that you need to have copied `ChmodBPF` from the .dmg file for Wireshark into the `/Library/StartupItems` folder as described in the 'Read me first' document.  `ChmodBPF` is a file located in the Utilities folder in the .dmg

Answer (score 1):

I just run it by doing

```
sudo open /Applications/Wireshark.app/
```